# Multiple Backgrounds updated with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some experience with css and various JavaScript libraries but I have been struggling on incorporating multiple backgrounds into this code I got off http://codepen.io/quasimondo/pen/lDdrF. I wanted to throw a transparent .png on top of the animated gradient.

I tried attaching the png to a different section of the website (body, div) which doesn't seem to work correctly as I lose some finer control of it.  Whenever I try to add to the $('#gradient').css function, it errors out.  I am assuming it is a simple syntax issue but I don't know.

Thanks for looking.  This is my first post, I searched through previous posts.  If I've missed something, sorry.

jason

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Animated Background Gradient</title>
<body>
<div id="gradient" />
</body>   
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Css

```
body{
background-color: #000000;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#gradient {
width: 100%;
height: 800px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;}
```

JS

```
var colors = new Array(
[62,35,255],[60,255,60],[255,35,98],[45,175,230],[255,0,255],[255,128,0]);

var step = 0;
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];

var gradientSpeed = 0.0006;

function updateGradient()
{

if ( $===undefined ) return;

var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];

var istep = 1 - step;
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "rgb("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+")";

var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "rgb("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+")";

$('#gradient').css({
background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});

step += gradientSpeed;
if ( step >= 1 )
{
step %= 1;
colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];

colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;

}
} 

setInterval(updateGradient,10);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/byjrglass/f7vsLss1/7/

Comment: What you mean "errors out"? .. that the png disappears?

Comment: And btw, it is not valid to put the `<script src="js/index.js"></script>` outside the `body` tags ... in this case after `</body>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into account that CSS Gradients behave like images. For example, this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, white);
```

produces the same thing as this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, white);
```

So to use an png image on top of that, you would need to do something like this:

```
background-image: url(image.png), linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, white)
```

Using your code, here's an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrJOQL

Or you could put the gradient in the body, instead of in the div, and include the image in the div. Here's an example using your code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPzWVo